# Getting empty layout when inflating it on onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecycleView` and it's items do scaling and transition animation when clicked. In the `onBindViewHolder()` I sometimes get `views` in post animation state and i'm trying to undo the scaling and transition that the animation did by saving the original layout positions and sizes and set it to the current layout in the viewHolder:

```
private void returnToOriginalSate(ItemViewHolder holder) {
    View groupLogo1 = holder.parent.findViewById(R.id.group_logo1);
    View groupLogo2 = holder.parent.findViewById(R.id.group_logo2);
    View leagueLogo = holder.parent.findViewById(R.id.league_logo_parent);

    groupLogo1.setX(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo1).getX());
    groupLogo1.setY(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo1).getY());
    groupLogo1.setLayoutParams(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo1).getLayoutParams());

    groupLogo2.setX(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo2).getX());
    groupLogo2.setY(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo2).getY());
    groupLogo2.setLayoutParams(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.group_logo2).getLayoutParams());

    leagueLogo.setX(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.league_logo_parent).getX());
    leagueLogo.setY(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.league_logo_parent).getY());
    leagueLogo.setLayoutParams(originalLayout.findViewById(R.id.league_logo_parent).getLayoutParams());
}
```

To get the `originalLayout` I'm inflating it and saving it in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_in_feed, parent, false));
    if(originalLayout == null){
        originalLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_in_feed, parent, false);

    }
    return viewHolder;
}
```

**The problem is that I get strange originalLayout values, for example an ImageView in this layout has LayoutParams: -1 and x,y position: (0,0)**

Why is that? How do I get the real originalLayout and is there a better way of doing that?

Edit: This is onbindview when I reset positions of the recycled view

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         if(this view is recycled and should be reset){
             returnToOriginalState(holder);

    }
}
```

Comment: onCreateViewHolder is called once after setting data list. Probably you should inflate it once and use viewHolder's view to apply animations on it.

Comment: originalLayout is how an item in the recycleView appears without the change in transition and scaling (the original layout (item_in_feed) in onCreateViewHolder with the original view's position)

Comment: Ok. I got it. You should add holder.mView.setOnClickListener(...) and pass holder view to the method and really apply animator/animation to it. What kind of animation do you need?

Comment: I'm using ObjectAmintor to do the animation in a onClick method, which means the transition and scaling really changes, I'm trying to reverse the animation by calling returnToOriginalState()

Answer (score 0):

Regarding our talk in comments apply reverse() to animator of the holders view when animation finished:

```
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        animation.removeListener(this);
        animation.setDuration(0);
        ((ValueAnimator) animation).reverse();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will result having the views animated and then reverse animated to the original position. I don't want that, I want to place the views in their original position in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Are you changing position of item?